# Is there a difference between Ca++ and Ca(2+)?

Tags: notation

In this [EKG tutorial](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rapid-Interpretation-EKGs-Methodology-Understanding/dp/0912912065) it says

> Depolarization conducts slowly through the AV node, since it is carried by slow moving $\ce{Ca++}$ ions...

Is there a difference between $\ce{Ca++}$ and $\ce{Ca}^{2+}$?

Comment: Welcome to the Chemistry StackExchange. I suppose that it would be more prudent to ask such yes/no questions on chat... So please, don't refrain from using the Periodic Table, the general discussion chat for Chemistry.StackExchange.com. Although, I'll admit, I'm not sure if this question is right at home here either... Also, google clears things up sometimes :)

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Are-Ca-and-Ca2-the-same-thing has the exact answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same.

The [IUPAC Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf#page=64) writes:

> $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ is commonly used in chemistry and recommended by [74]. The forms $\ce{Al^{+3}}$ and $\ce{S^{-2}}$, although widely used, are obsolete [74], as well as the old notation $\ce{Al^{+++}}$, $\ce{S^=}$, and $\ce{S^{--}}$.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this question is: No. There is no difference between the two, they are merely two different notations.

Comment: One of which is standard... $\ce{Y^X+}$ for compund Y, net charge X.